Configuring Notifications for CodeBuild in Terraform
I'm trying to configure sns (slack) notifications for CodeBuild in Terraform. By that I mean the 'create notification' lable in the console when we click on "actions". However, I couldn't find a way to do this via terraform (can't find documentation on it)
I know that in codepipeline, we can add actions for different stages, and attach a notification arn to each action like so:
action {
       configuration = {
         NotificationArn = var.approve_sns_arn
         CustomData      = var.approve_comment
       }
       name     = "Production-Approval"
       category = "Approval"
       owner    = "AWS"
       provider = "Manual"
       version  = "1"
     }

but I can't find a way to do this in codebuild.

Can you share where you saw that?

That one is not a CodeBuild feature per se, they just put it in a convenient location. It's a CodeStar notification: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/codestarnotifications_notification_rule
